# How to get the original transaction receipt for a subscription?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

In my app I'm trying to implement a Restore Purchases button, but I can't figure out how to get the latest purchase receipt for a subscription. I have only one SKProduct, an auto-renewable subscription.

I just need to obtain the latest receipt and send it to the server for verification.

I have tried this:

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
        for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) {
            if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing) {
                NSLog(@"Purchasing");
            }
            if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased) {
                NSLog(@"Purchasing");
            }
            if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored) {
                NSLog(@"Restored");
            }
            if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed) {
                NSLog(@"Failed");
            }
        }
}
```

But I'm getting this:

```
2013-10-04 12:21:48.994 App[5289:60b] Purchasing
2013-10-04 12:21:48.995 App[5289:60b] Purchasing
2013-10-04 12:21:48.996 App[5289:60b] Purchasing
2013-10-04 12:21:48.996 App[5289:60b] Purchasing
2013-10-04 12:21:48.997 App[5289:60b] Purchasing
2013-10-04 12:21:48.998 App[5289:60b] Purchasing
2013-10-04 12:21:48.999 App[5289:60b] Purchasing
2013-10-04 12:21:48.999 App[5289:60b] Purchasing
2013-10-04 12:21:49.000 App[5289:60b] Purchasing
2013-10-04 12:21:49.000 App[5289:60b] Restored
2013-10-04 12:21:49.001 App[5289:60b] Restored
2013-10-04 12:21:49.001 App[5289:60b] Restored
```

I just need the latest receipt. How can I get that?
The problem is that for some reason a user has purchased a subscription, but it failed to verify on my server. Why it failed - I don't know.

Comment: Why you need entire receipt? I think purchase date can accomplish your need.

Comment: Because I need to validate the receipt on my server to tell if it's active.

Comment: I am also stuck with the same issue. I want to get latest receipt. If a transaction is pending what we be there in the receipt?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can get the receipt:

## Swift

Fetch the Receipt Data
To retrieve the receipt data from the app on the device, use the appStoreReceiptURL method of NSBundle to locate the app’s receipt, and encode the data in Base64. Send this Base64-encoded data to your server.

```
// Get the receipt if it's available
if let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
    FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appStoreReceiptURL.path) {

    do {
        let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: appStoreReceiptURL, options: .alwaysMapped)
        print(receiptData)

        let receiptString = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])

        // Read receiptData
    }
    catch { print("Couldn't read receipt data with error: " + error.localizedDescription) }
}
```

## Objective-C

```
// Load the receipt from the app bundle.
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
if (!receipt) { 
    /* No local receipt -- handle the error. */ 
}
 
/* Read receiptData here... */
```

> For auto-renewable subscription items, parse the response to get information about the currently active subscription period. When you validate the receipt for a subscription, **latest_receipt**
> contains the latest encoded receipt, which is the same as the value
> for receipt-data in the request, and **latest_receipt_info** contains all
> the transactions for the subscription, including the initial purchase
> and subsequent renewals but not including any restores.

That's all you need I believe.

For more detail please check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html).